# Aggregation on field with period in value

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch

I'm trying to aggregate a list of the top users by number of posts. Query:

```
"top_users_posts" : {
  "terms" : {
    "size": 30,
    "field" : "user.username",
    "order": { "_count": "desc" }
  }
}
```

This results in some very strange data. Usernames must be at least 3 characters long, so it's impossible for someone to have the username "1" or "2".

```
"buckets": [
  {
    "key": "(real user)",
    "doc_count": 801
  },
  {
    "key": "1",
    "doc_count": 712
  },
  {
    "key": "(real user)",
    "doc_count": 614
  },
  {
    "key": "2",
    "doc_count": 587
  }
]
```

If I do a query for

```
{
  "term": {
    "user.username": 1
  }
}
```

I see that it matches usernames like `1.someuser`, `1.anotheruser` or `1.someoneelse23`. These are completely valid username in my application, however Elasticsearch is aggregating their posts together, rather than treating them separately because they have the same value before the period.

How do I change it so that it requires an exact match (or escape the period).

Comment: What do you mean it's fine?

Comment: _Elasticsearch is aggregating their posts together_.....my bad i missed this. Can you show what it does?

Comment: Well, when I run the first query above, it returns the results shown, where it has aggregated together the posts for any user whose username starts with `1.` into one bucket

Comment: What is the mapping of your `user.username` field? Whatever that mapping is, you need to use sub-fields and define a `not_analyzed` field there. Or, if you use ES 5.x, have a `keyword` subfield. For example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/multi-fields.html And then use that sub-field in your aggregation, instead of the `user.username` field.

Comment: Did you ever get an answer?